Can't open Android Studio after uninstalling Flutter and Dart extensions
I want to uninstall Flutter and Dart and reinstall again.
During the uninstall process, I uninstalled Flutter and Dart from the Visual Code Studio extension. and deleted the Flutter folder in C/Android/Flutter.
When I want to open Android Studio to download the Flutter and Dart plugin, the error is as shown:

I want to be able to open Android Studio again
